# Can we refer input path of s3 bucket for mapper and reducer for running MR job?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

I want to point my mapper and reducer to read input files from s3 bucket and store results in EMR cluster.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: One simple solution i am thinking of is copy s3 bucket data to emr for temporary purpose and pass same to mapper and reducer .This can be done with ease. But i am thinking can we directly point s3 bucket for read operation of input files. if yes what is the best solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the EMR getting started guides do exactly what you are asking for... Did you research this question before?

Answer (score 0):

You just [give `s3://bucket/key` syntax for your inputs and outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html)

You don't need to have EMR for [Hadoop to read/write to S3](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html)

But if you do, you [should use EMRFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-fs.html) with Consistency View for faster S3 reads